# Delphi 10.3 how messages routing in wincontrols work

Tags: delphi, winapi, custom-component, delphi-10.3-rio, windows-messages

I have this type of problem:

I need to be able to know when mouse cursor is inside my custom wincontrol that have other custom controls on it. Let me explain in a more graphical way:

[image: my custom scroll box with buttons on it]

```
component tree:
TForm
  |-- TMyCustomScrollBox
        |-- TMyCustomButton
        |-- TMyCustomButton
        |-- TMyCustomButton
        ...
```

TMyCustomButton controls are aligned alTop

Some explanation on what i do right now:

- i have captured CMMouseEnter and CMMouseLeave and WMMouseMove events on TMyCustomButton,
- and also am capturing CMMouseEnter and CMMouseLeave and WMMouseMove events on TMyCustomScrollBox,
- now i want TMyCustomScrollBox to know that mouse is inside of TMyCustomButton,
- i want to know when mouse leaves TMyCustomButton and if it is still inside TMyCustomScrollBox,
- and if mouse leaves TMyCustomScrollBox, i need to be able to capture CMMouseLeave on it.

What should i do to correctly do this, how to push messages from TMyCustomButton to TMyCustomScrollBox, because now i'm calling `inherited` inside CMMouseEnter / CMMouseLeave / WMMouseMove events, like:

```
procedure TUItemButton.CMMouseEnter(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Enabled then begin
    ButtonState := csHover;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TUItemButton.CMMouseLeave(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Enabled then begin
    ButtonState := csNone;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TUItemButton.WMMouseMove(var Msg: TWMMouseMove);
begin
  if Enabled then
    Repaint;
  inherited;
end;
```

Does inherited means: push this events to they'r corresponding parent wincontrol ?

Comment: Generally, `inherited;` means to call the same method in the ancestor class. You typically specify `inherited;` if you want to hook into a method's handling without altering the original behavior. If your class handles everything that should be done by that method, you don't call the inherited method. --- It's not entirely clear from your description what is happening vs. what you expected to (hoped would) happen.

Comment: Ok, i have good understanding how inheritance inside class works, but i don't understand how can i push specified events, that i capture in my component, into parent component that my component is placed on top of as a child.

Comment: @NevTon you would simply have the child pass the message to its `Parent` control's `WindowProc`

Comment: ... by using what ? SendMessage / PostMessage ? or maybe Perform ? I would like to understand how to do it in the proper way. But now, don't have clear picture of what is doing what in Delphi. In my understanding control that recives message can return Message.Result := 1; to signalize that it was handled, but if it return zero, this message is pushed to parent control. Now inherited in a class is calling ancestor if there is any, but somtime in my life i read that inherited in message behave in other way, is that right ? Or maybe i'm confusing something ?